# Rails - Iterate thru Multiple Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a more DRY way to iterate through some code.  I have a `User` model and I want to keep count of certain `Users` in a `ReportRecord` model (for reporting).

I have a defined list of values of `User.names` that I want to record (i.e. "Jan", "Lisa", "Tina").  How can I make this code more DRY as the list is much longer than three values?

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |u|

  # this part repeats with different names
  quantity = u.where("name = ?", "Jan").count
  ReportRecord.create(:user_id => u.id, :name => "Jan", :quantity => quantity)

  # repeated code with different name
  quantity = u.where("name = ?", "Lisa").count
  ReportRecord.create(:user_id => u.id, :name => "Lisa", :quantity => quantity)

  # repeated code with different name
  quantity = u.where("name = ?", "Tina").count
  ReportRecord.create(:user_id => u.id, :name => "Tina", :quantity => quantity)

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would sum all users first (1 query instead of 3):

```
quantity_by_name = User.select(:name).where(name: %w(Jan List Tina))
                       .group(:name).sum(:quantity)
#=> { 'Lisa' => 1, 'Jan' => 2, 'Tina' => 3 }
quantity_by_name.each do |name, quantity|
  ReportRecord.create(name: name, quantity: quantity)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
names = %w(Jan List Tina)

names.each do |name|
  count = User.where(name: name).count
  ReportRecord.create(name: name, quantity: count) # I don't understand `u.id`
end
```